# Invalid XQuery version 1.0-ml using oXygen XML Editor Personal Edition

Tags: validation, configuration, xquery, marklogic, oxygenxml

The personal edition of oXygen XML Editor flags a validation error when the MarkLogic dialect attribute is specified: `xquery version "1.0-ml"`

How can I configure the personal edition of oXygen XML Editor to ignore this validation error?

Changing the value to the strict form eliminates the error.
Example: `xquery version "1.0"`

Is the only solution essentially to comment files containing the MarkLogic server dialect command as follows:

```
(: xquery version "1.0-ml"; :)
xquery version "1.0";
```

Comment: https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/xquery/topic10842.html

Comment: Thank you, Mads. I appreciate the pointer to the article that explains only the enterprise edition supports the XQuery 1.0-ml dialect syntax.